# Prevent Node.js timing out on long DB requests

Tags: node.js

I'm running a Node.js server with Express.js and the 'mysql' package to make DB calls. This server makes requests to a MySQL database on an external machine. These requests involve large joins being executed, and take a long time, which I expect. Unfortunately, Node is impatient and even though for my purposes it's okay for these DB calls to take a long time, Node is returning a time-out error state on the DB call instead of waiting patiently for the data to come back. Is this configurable? How can I make Node wait patiently? Note, I know MySQL is returning queries correctly because an Apache/PHP server making the same query receives the correct response from MySQL without timing out.

Comment: What package are you using to execute the database queries?

Comment: Oops, felt like I was missing some info in my question... using the 'mysql' package. I'll update the question body to reflect this as well.

Comment: Ok no probs, see my answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the optional `timeout` option when you make a query

```
connection.query({sql: sqlString, timeout: 60000}, function () { ... });
```

[Reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#timeouts)

Comment: Thanks, embarrassing to miss that, I was trying to find the answer in the Node/Express docs for some reason.